# tranparent texture looks darker in 3d

Tags: 3d, stage3d

this is my experiment on 3d,i use stage 3d ,and i found i can't make the alpha texture looks properly,here's my snap shot

[image]

as it shows,the transparent pixel always looks darker in 3d. if i disable this line

```
context3D.setBlendFactors(Context3DBlendFactor.SOURCE_ALPHA,Context3DBlendFactor.ONE_MINUS_SOURCE_ALPHA)
```

it would display properly, but lose alpha feature.

i realized the blend factors formula actually made the pixel less color.but how can i fix it?i didn't find a way, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set it be

```
context3D.setBlendFactors(Context3DBlendFactor.ONE,Context3DBlendFactor.ONE_MINUS_SOURCE_ALPHA)
```

solved my problem .
two difference

(1,1,1,0.5)*(1,1,1,1)+(0,0,0,1)*(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5)=(1,1,1,0.5) correct

(1,1,1,0.5)*(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5)+(0,0,0,1)*(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5)=(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.75) not correct